# Optimization of operation using python

Tags: python, machine-learning

hi we operate a chiller (for air-conditioning) in a few buildings in our city, the way we operate is we turn the chiller on at 9am (the building opens at 10 am)  for precooling and add another chiller after 15 minutes, and add another one if needed on the next 15 minutes, this practice has been done a for a very long time. we have all sorts of data from the chiller itself, the pump, cooling tower, the building temperature as well as the weather. I want to know if the 15 minutes is just right or it can be delayed lets say 20,25 or 30 minutes (as it will have effect on energy savings) using a python program or machine learning algorithm. thank you

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to clarify what you is your priority.

Would you like to keep the temperature at 21C since 9:50AM at the lowest cost?

It might depend of the morning temperature how much time you need to start in advance your chillers.

On the other hand you might need to keep the temperature below 25C at any time because of regulations.

I guess the amount of chiller running will depend on the outside temperature and the amount of people in the building.

Maybe your power price is variable during the day.

Sure you can have some AI algorithm to estimate the cheapest operation but you will have to put all the data in there and you could probably start with no prediction algorithm at all and using a temperature weather forecast and a projected occupancy.

Comment: our target for the building is to be +/- 23.5 degC.... power cost here is approximately 9 per kwh